# How do I run an Ethernet cable through a doorway in a Mexican house built with brick and mortar?

Tags: doors, cables

I want to run an Ethernet cable from my DSL gateway to my room. My desk is about 10 meters away from the DSL gateway, and I need a way to run the cable through my room's doorway.

But here's the catch: I live in Mexico, and like most Mexican houses mine is built with brick and mortar, specialized DIY solutions are rather hard to find (if you can't find it at Home Depot you're pretty much toast), and my doorframes are a tiny, little, contemporary and minimalistic strip of wood affixed to the doorframe's structure. Googling in English turns up results that assume I live in an American house made out of wood and drywall with standard doorframes; googling in Spanish turns up nothing.

I am also pretty bad at handling cables. So much, that this was literally the reason why I got fired from my first job.

Any ideas on how to pass a cable through a doorway?

Comment: Could you run the cable above the ceiling, or below the floor?

Answer (score 4):

> **Any ideas on how to pass a cable through a doorway?**

Don't.

Drill a hole through the wall nearby and fit 8P8C (RJ45) outlets connected by solid (not stranded) UTP cable. An SDS drill will make this easier.

If necessary, chase channels up the wall (or down to trunking inside or alongside a baseboard/skirting) using tools designed for that job. You can use a hammer and bolster but there are power tools you might be able to buy or hire, including channeling chisel bits for SDS drills.

Comment: Brick is quite easy to drill, normally. Avoid the doorway; just pop a hole in the wall and run the cable through. If the surface is plastered in some way, cutting channels, laying wire, and re-plastering can make a very neat job.